# Omit JOIN if condition met

Tags: mysql, join

How to convert this query to handle the case when s.userId is equal to -1, in which case the JOIN should be omitted ?

```
SELECT s.*, u.type AS userType, u.email AS userEmail
FROM session s
JOIN users u ON ( u.user_id = s.userId )
WHERE ( s.storeId = ? )
ORDER BY s.timeUpdated DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.*, u.user_type AS userType, u.email AS userEmail
FROM session s
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.user_id = s.userId
WHERE ( s.storeId = ? )
ORDER BY s.timeUpdated DESC
```

Note, there will be some weird behavior if there is a user that has id `-1`, but I assume that never happens. Usually, though, we store `null` instead of a bogus value like `-1` to indicate that there is 'none' (in this case 'no user').

For the join it doesn't matter much, but by making the field nullable and storing null values, you can also create a foreign key constraint to the users table, so the other, non-null ids are verified to actually exist in the table. This is a way to ensure your data is valid. Without such constraints, you could also insert -5 or 300000 even if those users don't exist, which may lead to unpleasant surprises later.